# HTML Form autocomplete not working for INPUT controls inside an ASP.NET Update Panel

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have the following HTML element inside an ASP.NET update panel.

```
<input type='email' name='email' id='txtEmail' />
```

Is it because of AJAX postback?

Answer (score 0):

just add 
    `autocomplete="on"` 
inside the input tag

Comment: Did it but still it is not working. I have tried the W3Schools example (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) and it works in the browser. But it does not work inside an ASP.NET Update Panel.